# Multimethod union types don't support overloading correctly

Tags: python, multimethod

I'm using the `multimethod` package (1.4) to overload methods. I need to have Unioned types (or TypeVar) as the input types; however, this causes an issue. Example:

```
from typing import Union
from multimethod import multimethod


@multimethod
def func(x: int):
    print(x)

@multimethod
def func(x: int, y: int):
    print(x, y)

func(1)
func(2, 3)
```

This works fine, and outputs

```
1
2 3
```

As expected. However, this code crashes:

```
from typing import Union
from multimethod import multimethod


@multimethod
def func(x: int):
    print(x)

@multimethod
def func(x: Union[int, float], y: int):
    print(x, y)

func(1)
func(2, 3)
```

Output:

```
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\testing.py", line 14, in <module>
    func(2, 3)
  File "C:\Users\...\.conda\envs\...\lib\site-packages\multimethod\__init__.py", line 184, in __call__
    return self[tuple(map(self.get_type, args))](*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Is there a way to have union types *and* varying numbers of arguments? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't use *args?!

Comment: @OmarEhab, what does `*args` have to do with anything?

Comment: when you don't know how many argument will your function take put only *args as a parameter and it gives you a list af all arguments check this https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/

Comment: Your goal is to call the second `func` when the first argument is either an int or a float, right? As a workaround, you could provide separate overloads for them. That said, this looks like a bug or perhaps a missing feature, so I wonder if you checked the according bug trackers of the involved parts. BTW: It might be useful to provide more complete version info on the involved components and how you installed them.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes, but this is just a MRE. The real function has either 4 or 5 arguments, and each can be one two types, so that will lead to 48 method signatures, which is clearly no good :)

Comment: @OmarEhab, this is true, but the `multimethod` package uses a different approach (similar to C++ overloading) which tries to avoid several shortcomings of variable argument or keyword arguments. Using those would rather be a workaround than a solution. That is, if I'm guessing right what the OP wants to do.